# Array.prototype.indexOf() cannot find array inside of multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arrays = [[1, 2]],
        array = [1, 2],   
        index = arrays.indexOf(array);

console.log(index);
```

In the code above, the value of `index` is `-1`, indicating that the array `[1,2]` could not be found inside of `[[1,2]]`. The method works fine for one-dimensional arrays, but why doesn't it seem to work for multi-dimensional arrays? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It will compare object references, which are not the same for your arrays. In this case, you have to implement the search yourself.

Comment: Objects (incl. Arrays) are compared by **reference**, not by values. So: `[1, 2] !=  [1, 2]`